# An error that won't go away while coding Android in eclipse

Tags: android

I'm new to coding Java/Android and I'm using eclipse to do it.

I'm getting this error "***Syntax error, insert ")" to complete MethodInvocation***" at line "***b.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()***".

And "***Syntax error, insert "AssignmentOperator Expression" to complete Assignment***" at line "***});***"

And "***Syntax error, insert ";" to complete Statement***" at the next line "***}***" after "***});***"

I've checked the code multiple times and I can't seem to figure out why the errors won't go away. Any input would be very much appreciated.

I've already tried saving all files and restarting eclipse and no change.

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;

public class Main extends Activity {
/**
 * called when the activity is first created
 */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    Button b = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
    b.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            startActivity(new Intent(Main.this, Second.class));

        }
    });

}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_main, menu);
    return true;
}
}
```

Comment: Are the imports correct?

Comment: I believe they are, I've edited my original post to include imports as well.

Answer (score 3):

i get sometimes similar errors. a simple project clean helps (Project - clean)

Comment: I've just deleted all the new code I wrote and retyped them exactly the same as before and now the errors don't show anymore. Is this some sort of bug in eclipse? And what does project clean do exactly?

Comment: Clean takes the code that you've written and "rebuilds" it. Anything that may have been compiled before, will be redone. It helps with certain bugs.

Comment: seems to be a bug in the latest ADT update. i didn't get that error before. a project clean deletes all compiled class files as well as all the files that were generated (like R.java etc.) and rebuilds them all.

Comment: Yup going to Project and "clean"ing seems to do the trick! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
b.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
rest of your code....

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        Intent i = new Intent(this, second.class)
        startActivity(i);

    }
```